# Trying to display one part of an array, but its displaying all information

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Ok i have an array setup to pull information from the game server, such as current map and player count, there is more that one server in the array, i need to display all the information in different sections on the site, such as i want to display the informaton from one server under a section then another in a different section, here is the code that i have

HTML To display the information

```
                    <li><div id="serverstats-loading">Please wait ...<br /></div>
                    <div id="serverstats-wrapper" style="display: none"></div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $.post("query.php", {}, 
                                    function (data) {
                                        $('#serverstats-wrapper').html (data);
                                        $('#serverstats-loading').hide();
                                        $('#serverstats-wrapper').show ();
                                    });
                            });
                        </script>
```

Array in php

```
$servers = array (array ('name' => 'DatGamer PvP Sever',
                         'ip' => '89.163.145.206',
                         'port' => 5000),
                  array ('name' => 'DatGamer RP Server',
                         'ip' => '89.163.145.206',
                         'port' => 19000));

$cachelifetime = 30;
$cachefile = './cache/servers.html';

$output = '<a href ="steam://connect/#ip#:#port#">#name#</a><br />#map#              #players#/#maxplayers#<br /><br />';

?>
```

Screenshot of what it looks like on the site

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FahKE.jpg

The pvp sever stays, but the RP one needs to displayed under a different location.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, if you need any more information on this i will do my best to give it.

Thank you
-AcidzDesigns

Answer (score 0):

Well if I got you correct you need to change the logic you use.

1) Return from server not links but json with properties and key "PvP"/"RP" value
2) use 
some html template to render retuned json into proper section

or if you need to return html from server than return two arrays/dictionary for PvP and RP separately

Comment: Can you show an example or write the code for me, as i only understand a little of what you say

Comment: ok, I am not a php guy but I will try

`$arr = array ('pvp'=>'array of links for pvp','rp'=>'array of links for rp');

echo json_encode($arr)
'



javascript


`$(document).ready(function(){
  $.post("query.php", {}, 
    function (data) {
      $('#pvp').html (data['pvp']);
      $('#rp').html (data['rp']);
      $('#serverstats-loading').hide();
      $('#serverstats-wrapper').show ();
  });
});'


this is very basic example, I would suggest for you to use some jquery templates for html rendering

Comment: whee does this need to go to?

Comment: you need to return from server json with two properties: 'PvP' and 'RP'. On client side when you get this json you simply pass to proper div tag html from server like this: `$('#pvp').html (data['pvp']); `